# Output table from 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm trying to get this data to output as a table, but I haven't been able to make a functional 2d array table with any method I've tried. I'm trying to make a 7x2 matrix for gradeList and devList.

I'm taking pre-initialized and user input data into 3 arrays. I'm trying to make a table out of two of them (and then use the other as labels). nameList would be the label for the rows, and 'grade' and 'deviation' would be the labels for the columns (I haven't tried to set that yet).

I've commented out the first attempt, which output the correct information but couldn't make a readable table. The program compiles, but throws an error any time I run it with the current attempt at a matrix.

Sorry if I've forgotten any useful info and thanks for looking.

```
    //This program determines the mean grade and deviation from that mean for a class of users.

    import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradeArrays
{    
   static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   static int avg;

   //array declarations
   static String[] nameList = {"Doc","Grumpy","Happy","Sleepy","Dopey","Sneezy","Bashful"};
   static int[] gradeList = new int[7];
   static int[] devList = new int[7];

   //main method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("This program will calculate the mean, and the deviation from that mean, for 7 students.");

      getGrades(gradeList);

      meanCalc(gradeList);      

      devCalc(gradeList, avg);

      tableOut(gradeList, devList, avg);
   }

   //input scores from user, method 1
   public static int[] getGrades(int[] gradeList)
   {

      for (int i=0; i < nameList.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("What is the grade for " + nameList[i] + "?");
         gradeList[i]= in.nextInt();
      }

      return gradeList;
   }


   //calculate average, method 2
   public static int meanCalc(int[] gradeList)
   {
      int sum = 0;   

      for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++)
      {
         sum = sum + gradeList[i];
      }

         if (gradeList.length !=0)
         {   
            avg = sum / gradeList.length;
         }

         else
         {
            avg = 0;
         }

      return avg;
   }

   //calculate deviation, method 3
   public static int[] devCalc(int[] gradeList, int avg)
   {  
      for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++)   
      {
         devList[i] = gradeList[i] - avg;
      }

      return devList;

   }


   //output, method 4
   public static void tableOut(int[] gradeList, int[] devList, int avg)
   {  
      /*
      System.out.println("   Student  Grade  Deviation");

      for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++)
      {   
         System.out.print("   " + nameList[i] +  "   ");
         System.out.print("   " + gradeList[i] + "   ");
         System.out.printf("   " + "%7d", devList[i]); 
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println("The average grade was " + avg + ".");
      */

      int[][] outTable = new int[7][2];

      for (int row = 0; row < nameList.length; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
         {
            outTable[row][col] = 21;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could take credit for them. Part of the assignment (also set in 'a remote Appalachian town.')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void tableOut(int[] gradeList, int[] devList, int avg)
        {  

           System.out.println("\tStudent\tGrade\tDeviation");

           for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++)
           {   
              System.out.print("\t" + nameList[i] +  "\t");
              System.out.print("\t" + gradeList[i] + "\t");
              System.out.printf("\t" + "%7d", devList[i]); 
              System.out.println();
           }
           System.out.println("The average grade was " + avg + ".");


           int[][] outTable = new int[7][2];

           for (int row = 0; row < nameList.length; row++)
           {
              for (int col = 0; col <2; col++)
              {
                 outTable[row][col] = 21;

              }
           }
        }
```

This code works properly... Try this.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to realize my problem was with the actual output and not somewhere in the setup of the arrays.